# how could a textarea tag be sorted alphabeticaly and outputted in another textarea tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering how the contents of a `<textarea>` tag could be sorted alphabetically and then outputted in another second `<textarea>` tag using javascript.

There are some questions similar to this one asked before on StackOverflow but I don't think that any of their answers can be applied to my code below.

Here is my code:

```css
.con {
    display: flex; 
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.txt {
    display: flex; 
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.text {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 630px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    resize: none;
}

.asci {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.ascii {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 640px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>alphabetical order machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ascii.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="con">
    <form class="txt">
        <textarea class="text"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="type your text here"></textarea>        
        <input class="button" type='button' value="alphabetize" onclick="">
    </form>
    <form class="asci">
        <textarea class="ascii" id="output" type="text" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
    </form>
    </div>
    <script src="ascii.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: what do you want to alphabetize? each word in the text area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too would start with split but let's not reinvent the world.  you can use the js array sort, toString and replace methods in a 4 line function

```js
function myFunction(){
   var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
   var textArray = text.split(" ").sort();
   var output= document.getElementById('output');
   output.value = textArray.toString().replace(/,/g," ");
}
```

```css
.con {
    display: flex; 
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.txt {
    display: flex; 
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.text {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 630px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    resize: none;
}

.asci {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.ascii {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 640px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>alphabetical order machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ascii.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="con">
    <form class="txt">
        <textarea class="text"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="type your text here"></textarea>        
        <input class="button" type='button' value="alphabetize" onclick="myFunction()">
    </form>
    <form class="asci">
        <textarea class="ascii" id="output" type="text" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
    </form>
    </div>
    <script src="ascii.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya, yours is way neater than mine.

Comment: yeah, but yours works too and if it ain't broken don't fix it!

Answer (score 2):

First I would begin with `split()`ting the value of the `textarea` element into an array:

```js
//split the value on a space character
let wordsArr = document.querySelector('#input').value.split(' ');
```

Then sort the array:

```js
wordsArr.sort((a, b) => {
    const word1 = a.toUpperCase();
    const word2 = b.toUpperCase();
    if (word1 < word2) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (word2 > word1) {
        return 1;
    }
    /* if neither of those if statements fire, that means the words are the 
    same and can stay in the same position */
    return 0;
};
```

Then join the array elements back into a single string, and set that as the value of the other textarea:

```js
document.querySelector('#output').value = wordsArr.join(' ');
```

MDN Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `split()` and `sort()`.
Here is your code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const input1 = document.getElementById("input");
  const input2 = document.getElementById("output");
  
  let content = input1.value; //Get its content
  var array = content.split(" "); //And replace each space by a comma to make an array.
  
  input2.value = array.sort();    //alphabetize it!
  input2.value = input2.value.replace(",", " "); //Restore the spaces.
}
```

```css
.con {
    display: flex; 
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.txt {
    display: flex; 
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.text {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 630px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    resize: none;
}

.asci {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.ascii {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 640px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>alphabetical order machine</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="con">
    <form class="txt">
        <textarea class="text"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="type your text here"></textarea>        
        <input class="button" type='button' value="alphabetize" onclick="myFunction();">
    </form>
      <form class="asci">
          <textarea class="ascii" id="output" type="text" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Register the 'input' and the 'click' event to form. Create an event handler for each event.

   ```
   document.forms.ID.oninput = inputHandler;
   document.forms.ID.onclick = clickHandler;
   ```
2. When creating event handlers, pass the event object

   ```
   function inputHandler(e) {...
   ```
3. Define variables that reference:

   **A NodeList of all form fields**

   ```
   /* 
   - "this" is the form tag
   - .elements is a property that collects all form type tags
   */
   const field = this.elements;
   ```

   **The tag user interacted with**

   ```
    /*
    - e.target property always points to the tag a user has clicked, changed,   
      entered data upon, etc.
   */
   const input = e.target;
   ```

   **Any other relevant tags like an output**

   ```
   /*
   - Any input, output, textarea, etc you want to access just prefix the NodeList
     identifier (see first variable) to any form type tag #id or [name]
   */
   const output = field.output;
   ```
4. Next, define a conditional that will determine which tag you want to deal with (usually `e.target`) and nothing else. By excluding other unnecessary tags, you have complete control of what does what and how it's done.

   ```
   if (e.target.id === 'input') {...
   /* OR */
   if (e.target.className === 'button') {...
   ```

---

#### Demo

```js
const form = document.forms.editor;

form.oninput = copyText;
form.onclick = sortText;

function copyText(e) {
  const ui = this.elements;
  const inp = e.target;
  const out = ui.output;

  if (inp.id === 'input') {
    out.value = inp.value;
  }
}

function sortText(e) {
  const ui = this.elements;
  const btn = e.target;
  const out = ui.output;

  if (btn.className === "button") {
    let result = out.value.split(' ').sort((a, b) => a - b);
    out.value = result;
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

textarea {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 30vw;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 90vh;
  height: 5vw;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="editor">
    <fieldset>
      <textarea id="input" placeholder="Enter a space-delimited list of items here"></textarea>
      <button class="button" type='button'>Sort</button>
      <textarea id="output" placeholder="Sorted list will be provided here"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```